# Sorting arrays using React js

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to display array values sorted by `OrderId` field. Here is my code:

```
var fields = 
    [{value: "Claims", OrderId:3 },
     {value: "Requests", OrderId:1 },
     {value: "Access", OrderId: 2}]

var listElements = fields.sort('OrderId', function(n){ return Math.sin(n) } )
    .map( function(field) {
        return React.createElement('li', {},
            React.createElement('h2',{}, field.value)

        )
    })
var rootElement =
    React.createElement('div', {},
        React.createElement('ul', {}, listElements)

    )

ReactDOM.render(rootElement, document.getElementById('container'));
```

This does not give me errors and displays the values in a desired format but unsorted... How can I sort in Reactjs world?

Comment: Well, where is the sortBy method from?

Comment: I love lodash for this kind of thing. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

Comment: You have doublequotes in `OrderId:3"`. I take it si typo that is not present in the code.

Comment: sorry, these were all typos. the actual array is more complicated so I made it simple and made some typos along the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all check your field name it should be **OrderId** for all the three, in question it is not and remove any extra quotes as well.

Then for sorting purpose, i dont know about sortBy method, you can use sort method easily, check out this example code below, and let me know if it will work for you -

JS fiddle link - 
https://jsfiddle.net/4kq4vbdw/

```
var fields = 
 [{value: "Claims", OrderId:3 },
 {value: "Requests", OrderId:1 },
 {value: "Access", OrderId: 2}];

fields.sort(function(a,b){
 return parseInt(a.OrderId)  - parseInt(b.OrderId);
})
 console.log(fields);
```